# How to group csv in python without using pandas

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with 3 rows: "Username", "Date", "Energy saved" and I would like to sum the "Energy saved" of a specific user by date.

[image]

For example, if `username = 'merrytan'`, how can I print all the rows with "merrytan" such that the total energy saved is aggregated by date? (Date: 24/2/2022 Total Energy saved = 1001 , Date: 24/2/2022 Total Energy saved = 700)

I am a beginner at python and typically, I would use pandas to resolve this issue but it is not allowed for this project so I am at a complete loss on where to even begin. I would appreciate any help and guidance. Thank you.

Comment: If you are not allowed to use pandas in this project, how do you read the data? Have you tried a specific approach to share with us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My alternative to opening csv files is to use csv module of native python. You read them as a "file" and just extract the values that you need. I filter using the first column and keep only keep the equal index values from the concerned column. (which is thrid and index 2.)

```
import csv

energy_saved = []
with open(r"D:\test_stack.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
    file = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in file:
        if row[0]=="merrytan":
           energy_saved.append(row[2])
    energy_saved = sum(map(int, energy_saved))
```

Now you have a list of just concerned values, and you can sum them afterwards.

Edit - So, I just realized that I left out the time part of your request completely lol. Here's the update.

```
import csv
my_dict = {}
with open(r"D:\test_stack.csv", newline="") as file:
    for row in csv.reader(file):
        if row[0]=="merrytan":
             my_dict[row[1]] = my_dict.get(row[1], 0) + int(row[2])
```

So, we need to get the date column of the file as well. We need to make a presentation of two "rows" but when Pandas has been prohibited, we will go to dictionary with *date* as keys and *energy* as values.

But your *date* column has repeated values (regardless intended or else) and Dictionaries require keys to be unique. So, we use a loop. You add one *date* value after another as key and corresponding *energy* as value to the new dictionary, but when it is already present, you will sum with the existing value instead.

Comment: Good start. You need to go back and read the request, I see OP asking for sums binned by date… and there’s a typo in the question… 700 should be for 2/25 (not 24).

Comment: Yep. I just noticed how I have left out a step of the request. Thanks lol

Answer (score 0):

I would turn your CSV file into a two-level dictionary, with username and then date as the keys

```py
infile = open("data.csv", "r").readlines()
savings = dict()

# Skip the first line of the CSV, since that has the column names
# not data
for row in infile[1:]:
    username, date_col, saved = row.strip().split(",")
    saved = int(saved)
    if username in savings:
        if date_col in savings[username]:
            savings[username][date_col] = savings[username][date_col] + saved
        else:
            savings[username][date_col] = saved
    else:
        savings[username] = {date_col: saved}
```

Comment: Why recommend hand-parsing the CSV, instead of using the well-tested and spec-compliant CSV module in the standard library?

Comment: Laziness on my part, and I believe there's value in knowing how to write a solution when you really don't have useful modules available to you.